Chat event #1 - meet the moderators
Us moderators have colluded and found a time we can all make for the first chatcast event (see the link for the proposed idea).
The first chatcast thing will be on (Monday) the 28th of November at 19:00 UTC for one hour. Of course, the event can overrun if demand is there.
The topics will be: 

meet the moderators
questions and ideas for moderation
general how we think the beta is going
and whatever you want to talk about. 

The rules of chat are much, much more relaxed that the main format. The goal is to get an idea of who the moderators are (as opposed to just a bunch of guys with diamonds) and generally use the chat system a bit, kick around some ideas.
So, we'll hold the event in chat and you can subscribe yourself to the scheduled event here (for a reminder). We'll also put up a site notice to remind people who don't check meta.
Finally, afterwards we can bookmark useful parts (I shall talk to rchern about our powers in this regard) for safekeeping and for reference. This means they'll be publicly accessible forever. 
So, come along. Hope to see lots of people there.
Update We have moved this to the following Monday so Paulo can definitely make it. I felt it was important we mods could definitely all make it.

So, chat meeting number 1 took place and was a success I feel!
If you wish to view the transcript, you can find it here. I shall edit key points into this answer at some point; others feel free to do so if you have the time.
